# AES (rijndael) decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I have a Security class that Encode and Decode string, but when I try do decode - something going wrong.

Here is my Security class:

```
class Security
{
    public static String encrypt(String imput, String key)
    {
        String cipherText;
        var rijndael = new RijndaelManaged()
        {
            Key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key),
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            BlockSize = 128,
            Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
        };
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(rijndael.Key, null);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(imput);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                cipherText = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String imput, String key)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imput);
        String decrypted;

        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijAlg.BlockSize = 128;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, null);
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        decrypted = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

In program.cs:

```
String A = Security.encrypt("text", "1234567891234567");
A = Security.decrypt(A, "1234567891234567");
```

Finaly it return something like that: �%����;\0�\a��f6 , but I need original string. Where I made a mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key) == Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)`?

Comment: You're right. I did not notice that I used different formats. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same encoding in both methods, either Encoding.Unicode or Encoding.UTF8

Comment: You're right. I did not notice that I used different formats. Thank you.